# Get value from datepicker in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I use datepicker from kartik. I use it with field range and I want to make a search function from it. But, I can't get value or store value to a variable from it. How to solve it?

This is the code:

```
<?php
            // With Range
            $layout3 = <<< HTML
                <span class="input-group-addon" style="background: #e9e9e6;">Tanggal Awal</span>
                {input1}
                <!--<span class="input-group-addon" style="background: #e9e9e6;">aft</span>
                {separator}-->
                <span class="input-group-addon" style="background: #e9e9e6;">Tanggal Akhir</span>
                {input2}
                <span class="input-group-addon kv-date-remove" style="background: #e9e9e6;">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                </span>
HTML;

            echo DatePicker::widget([
                'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
                'name' => 'dp_addon_3a',
                'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'name2' => 'dp_addon_3b',
                'value2' => date('Y-m-d'),
                // 'separator' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-horizontal"></i>',
                'layout' => $layout3,
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'autoclose' => true,
                    'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                ]
            ]);
            $value = 'value';
            $value2 = 'value2';
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful to you.
Following is the layout code.

```
 <?php

    use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
    use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
    use yii\helpers\Url;
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use kartik\date\DatePicker;

    $model = new MyAllocation();
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'id' => 'allocation',
                'method' => 'post',
                'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                ],
            ]);  
    ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php 
                    echo '<label class="control-label">Allocation Date</label>';
                    echo DatePicker::widget([
                       'name' => 'WorkAllocation[allocation_datetime]',
                       'value' => date('d-m-Y'),
                       'type' => 1,
                       'pluginOptions' => [
                           'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                           'todayHighlight' => true,
                           'class' => 'form-control',
                       ],
                   ]);
                ?>
        </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Allocate', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name' => 'submit']) ?>
    </div>
```

And Following is the Controller code :

```
<?php

use app\modules\work\models\WorkAllocation;
 public function actionYouractionname() 
        {
            if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->isAjax) 
             {
                $data = Yii::$app->request->post();

                // var_dump($data);

                $model->allocation_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data['WorkAllocation']['allocation_datetime']));
                $model->save();
            }
        }
```

Comment: How can I get the value without have a model?

Comment: var_dump($_POST);  you will get all parameters including Date in post.
then use it as per your need.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have tried the controller on the top but I get error. It says not have 'Allocation'. And how about the button for the action?

Comment: @RiefSapthana : I have updated my answer. Plese check. Might be helpful to you. :)

Comment: I'm sorry again. But I don't have new model to get the value. Can I store the value in the variable?

Comment: I'm not pretty much sure, But you can try it.
  $datevrbl = $_POST['someModel']['example'];

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<?php 
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => ['your_action'],
        'method' => 'method_you_want',
    ]); 
?>
<?=
    $form->field($model, 'dateattribute')->widget(DatePicker::className(),
    [
        // config of your datepicker
    ]); 
?>
```

the value of the date picker will be store in your model. In your controller you have to instance a new object of your model :

```
$model = new YourModel();
return $this->render('your_action', ['model' => $model]);
```

Hope I was clear do not hesitate to ask if not :)

Comment: Can I make my own dateattribute? because I only have one attribute for date. Whereas I want to get 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

In your view try this

```
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
    <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php 
                    echo '<label class="control-label">Allocation Date</label>';
                    echo DatePicker::widget([
                       'name' => 'Allocation[allocation_datetime]',
                       'value' => date('d-m-Y'),
                       'type' => 1,
                       'pluginOptions' => [
                           'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                           'todayHighlight' => true,
                           'class' => 'form-control',
                       ],
                   ]);
                ?>
        </div>
```

In your Controller

```
$model->allocation_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data['Allocation']['allocation_datetime']));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is an error undefined variable data

Comment: public function actionYouractionname() {
        if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->isAjax)
 {
            $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
$model->allocation_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data['Allocation']['allocation_datetime']));
$model->save();
}